# Help solve ${{z}^{3}}=\overline{z}$ ($z\in \mathbb{C}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Me and my friend try to solve

$${{z}^{3}}=\overline{z}$$ 
where $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

My way to solve it was:

$\operatorname{cin}(\theta )=\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i$

\begin{align}
  & z=r \operatorname{cin}(\theta ),\overline{z}=r\operatorname{cin}(-\theta +2\pi k) \\ 
 & {{z}^{3}}={{r}^{3}}\operatorname{cin}(3\theta ) \\ 
 & {{z}^{3}}=\overline{z} \\ 
 & {{r}^{3}}\operatorname{cin}(3\theta )=r\operatorname{cin}(-\theta +2\pi k) \\ 
 & {{r}^{3}}=r\Leftrightarrow {{r}^{3}}-r=0\Leftrightarrow r({{r}^{2}}-1)=0\Leftrightarrow r=\pm 1,r=0\Leftrightarrow r=1 \\ 
 & 3\theta =-\theta +2\pi k\Leftrightarrow 4\theta =2\pi k\Leftrightarrow \theta =\frac{\pi k}{2} \\ 
\end{align}

So my solution for k=0,1,2 :

$\begin{align}
  & {{z}_{1}}=\cos (0)+\sin (0)i=1+0i \\ 
 & {{z}_{2}}=\cos (\frac{\pi }{2})+\sin (\frac{\pi }{2})i=0+1i \\ 
 & {{z}_{3}}=\cos (\pi )+\sin (\pi )i=-1+0i \\ 
\end{align}$

My friend on the other hand solve it like this:

$\begin{align}
  & {{z}^{3}}=\bar{z} \\ 
 & {{z}^{3}}\cdot z=\bar{z}\cdot z \\ 
 & {{z}^{4}}=|z{{|}^{2}} \\ 
\end{align}$

He got the same solutions expect he got one more solution than me 
${{z}_{4}}=\cos (\pi )+\sin (\pi )i=0-i \\$

What is the right solution and why?

Comment: What is $\bar z$ in $\mathbb Z$ ??

Comment: Why do you stop at $k=2$? What happens if you fill in $k=3$?

Comment: @Uncountable when you solve equation with ${{z}^{3}}$ don't you need to have only 3 solutions?

Comment: I think you are confusing with polynomials (for a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ the maximum number of zeros (roots) is the degree of the polynomial). $f(z)=z^3-\overline{z}$ is not a polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ (since it cannot be expressed as $a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_nz^n$ with $a_0,\cdots,a_n\in\mathbb{C}$), so it may have more than $3$ zeros, i.e. $z^3-\overline{z}=0$ can have more than $3$ solutions (and in fact it does).

Comment: Note that $0$ is a solution! Why/how did you rule that out as a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|z^3|=|z|^3$ and $|\bar{z}|=|z|$ so that for equality we require

$$|z|^3=|z| \underset{z\neq 0}{\Rightarrow} |z|^2=1\underset{|z|\geq 0}{\Rightarrow} |z|=1.$$

Note $0^3=\bar{0}$ so is a solution.

So we have $|z|=1$ so $z=e^{i\theta}$ and we want

$$z^3=\bar{z}\Rightarrow e^{3i\theta}=e^{-i\theta}\Rightarrow 3\theta\equiv -\theta\,\,\text{mod } 2\pi.$$

This gives you, for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
$$\begin{align}
3\theta&=-\theta+2k\pi
\\ \Rightarrow 4\theta&=2k\pi
\\ \Rightarrow \theta&=k\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}$$

It remains to this gives you the non-zero solutions $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is right. Although there is nothing wrong with your method.  There is no reason to stop at $k=2$. For $k=3$,

$$\cos\frac{3\pi}2+i\sin\frac{3\pi}2=i$$

When $k=4$, we get $1$ again and so there are no more solutions.

Comment: The problem is that i thought that when you solve ${{z}^{n}}$ you can only  get n solutions , and here i get 4 solutions but i solve for solve ${{z}^{3}}$

Comment: That would be true for a polynomial equation. Because $\overline z$ is involved, the equation is not polynomial.